# RxJava очередь запросов или запрос в цикле

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Использую Rx, обращаюсь в сеть и в запросе передаю параметр.

этих параметров несколько, `List<String> paramsValue;`
Выполняю так:

```
for(String p : paramsValue)
    Flowable f = QRequests.get(p);
```

Как можно создать очередь на выполнение средствами rx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(paramsValue).flatMap {
    QRequests.get(it)
}
```

Или

```
Flowable.fromIterable(paramsValue).concatMap {
    QRequests.get(it)
}
```